# How do I access dynamic elements in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating some divs using `v-for`:

```html
<div class="foo" v-for="bar in bars">{{bar.text}}</div>
```

The data for the divs comes from an Axios request:

```js
created() {
  axios('get/data').then( response => {
    this.bars = response.data;
  });
}
```

This all works fine and renders properly.

However, once they're created, I want to access the divs to find out things like `getBoundingClientRect`, and this is where I get stuck.

I don't understand why `this.$el.querySelectorAll('.foo')` doesn't work when `this.$el` clearly has all the .foo divs in it. I assume it's something to do with the DOM not yet having been updated, but I don't understand how one bit works while the other doesn't.

```js
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$el); //Outputs all the .foo divs
  console.log(this.$el.querySelectorAll('.foo')); //Outputs empty array
}
```

Using `this.$el.querySelectorAll('.foo')` in `updated()` works fine, but I only need to run the code once, not on every update.

Vue version is 2.6.10

Comment: i didnt test this but i think you can give each div a ref based on it's index and work with $refs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$nextTick` **after** the data was loaded, which should show the `div` tags

```js
created() {
  axios('get/data')
  .then( response => {
    this.bars = response.data;

    this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log(this.$el.querySelectorAll('.foo')); 
    });
  });
}
```

As to why you're getting the seemingly strange behaviour, my theory is this...

`this.$el` logs an object that keeps updating even after the instance gets mounted. The `this.$el.querySelectorAll` however returns a snapshot at the time.

That said, using `this.$el.querySelectorAll` should be avoided when possible in lieu of `$refs`. However you will see the same issue, and if you have dynamically generated repeating content (like when using `v-for`) and/or if you're interfacing it with another library, `querySelectorAll` may be a better option.

Comment: Unfortunately`$nextTick` just gives me a blank array as before when run in `mounted()`

Comment: Right, I forgot that you're using the axios response to populate the data, so the dom cannot be updated until the data is loaded. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With vuejs better using `$ref`

[$Ref Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)

```
<div ref="myElement"/>

mounted(){
  const { myElement} = this.$refs;
  console.log(myElement)
}
```

then you have more control on your element

Comment: Using `$refs` I seem to have a similar problem. `$refs` shows the divs in an object, but if I try to access them they just come out as undefined. I think it's the same issue this person had: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/accessing-refs/15049